# Android add multiple MYSQL rows using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

Basically I know how to add one row to an external mysql database using android. Now im looking to add multiple rows at once. Heres my code so far.

PHP Script

```
<?php
$host="db4free.net"; //replace with database hostname 
$username="xxxxxx"; //replace with database username 
$password="xxxxxxx"; //replace with database password 
$db_name="xxxxxxx"; //replace with database name

$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
/*  Get the value in the whichfunction parameter
 sent from the android application which will
determine the fucntion to call.   */

$getFunctionToCall = $_POST['whichfunction'];


/*  Depending on the value of the whichfunction
 parameter switch to call different function */

switch ($getFunctionToCall){
    case "AddUser":
        echo AddUser($_POST['name'],$_POST['password']);
        break;
}

/* Function to add user to the user table */

function AddUser($name,$password){
    $sql = "insert into users(name,password) values('$name','$password')";
    if(mysql_query($sql)){
        return 1; // Return 1 for success;
    }else{
        return 2;// Return 2 for database error;
    }
}
?>
```

Android Method

```
protected void SendToPhpFile() {

   ArrayList<NameValuePair> pp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


   pp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("whichfunction", "AddUser"));

    String[] names = {"David","Jimmy","Shane"};
    String[] passwords = {"mypass1","mypass2","mypass3"};



  for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    pp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("names[]", String.valueOf(names[i])));
    pp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passwords[]", String.valueOf(passwords[i])));
}


 try{
        status = "";
        status = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(ConnectBase.link, pp);
        String res=status.toString();
        res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");

        /* Depending on value you return if insert was successful */
            if(res.equals("1")){
                Toaster("Data successfully added.");
            }else{
                Toaster(status);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toaster("Data successfully added: " + e.toString());
        } 

}
```

So I think I have the android size more or less sorted but I'm not 100%. If you guys could come up with a solution to how I've started that would be great. I've got zero experience with php so don't really know where to start when adding more than 1 row.
Thank you

Comment: 1. To insert multiple rows run multiple `INSERT` queries. 2. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, do not use these functions to write new code. Use [PDO](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
INSERT INTO table (name, password ) VALUES ('Name1', 'Password1'), ('Name2', 'Password2'),('Name3', 'Password3'), ('Name4', 'Password4')
```

Comment: Only problem with this is that the array will be dynamicaly sized. The string array is just a tester, will be replaced by a dynamic String array

Answer (score 0):

Using **mysqli** you can not only **avoid deprecated mysql functions** but you can easily loop over insert values using prepared statements.

[Referencing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

In the following example we will be inserting usernames and passwords into the database in a safe and efficient way.

```
$x = array(array('bob','mypasswordlol'),array('your_mother','knitting5000'));
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (`username`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?)");
foreach ( $x AS $k => $value) {
    $stmt->bind_param($stmt, "ss", $value[0], $value[1]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
// close your connection
```

Hopefully this helps. Prepared statements are the bees knees when it comes to mysqli. It will help you prevent database injection and increase performance as well!

Comment: Hey Calebj, Thanks for the response! I would have to define the array in the android code and it would have no defined size...Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand how you can reference the android array in the php

Comment: If you create a hashmap http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html of username/password combinations then json serialize them. you can json_decode() in php and get everything nice and cleanly. You may not even have to json serialize.